# Эффект при скроллинге. Подскажите его название

Tags: прокрутка, parallax

Сайт компании apple поражает своими эффектами. Как называется данный примененный эффект, когда X заменятся телефоном, при этом объект двигается, когда пролистываешь страницу вниз? И как сделать его? покидайте ресурсы и названия языков (и их библиотек) для создания подобного

вот здесь применен этот эффект.
https://www.apple.com/uk/iphone-x/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Scrollmagic.io](http://scrollmagic.io/), нечто подобное